# Can I (a minor) travel to, live in and study in South Korea by myself?

Tags: south-korea, study, new-zealand-citizens

I really want to study in South Korea as it has been continuously voted as 1st place on the education system and literary tests for people my age. So, I've come to the conclusion that studying in Korea would be the best option for me in order to have a well educated future. The only problem being, that I can't find a suitable visa for me, so I'm starting to wonder if there is even one out there that fits my situation. My mother gives her full permission for me to go (but is still quite hesitant on coming herself) , I carry a New Zealand citizenship but I live in Australia (where I'll get a citizenship within the next year or so) and I'm only 13 years old.

So, if any one you know any visas that may be suitable for me, or if you know anything else that may help, please respond to this with the information.
Thank you :)

Comment: Do you speak any Korean? Also, are you familiar with "Hell Korea"? (Google it.) There's a price to pay for those high test scores.

Comment: It is truly commendable on how far you willing to go and get a better education for yourself but you need to also consider the hit your performance will take in a completely alien culture. You might or might not be better off looking for a better school in your home country. But, again, if this is what you want after a careful evaluation of options, go for it!

Comment: A major cause of the Korean education performance may be schools and parents pushing students to study and succeed. It sounds as though you are fully capable of pushing yourself. I suggest looking for an Australian school that offers, and does well on, the International Baccalaureate.

Comment: The test scores mean nothing. It's just some dead, rote learning materials which have nothing to do with how well one actually does as an adult, in the job market and how well one actually acquires modern, practical skills etc. and it has much to do with the peculiar culture of Korea instead of any real "education" in any terms. Just looking at the test scores would be a laughable way to choose education, to be honest. You're missing the point. I'm not sure if you're serious or not but your mother really should have known better about this subject.

Comment: What really matters is the resources and comparative strengths of this school/place etc. If you're in the US/Australia etc. you'd be in a much better position to advance to the corresponding higher ed institutions (universities) in those countries, while if you're in Korea then no matter how high you score in the standaridized tests it means little and universities in other countries will have very limited quotas for you. Also the job market and prospect after you graduate are highly local and have everything to do with the location and resources and nothing to do with test scores.

Comment: In all it's really sad to see people putting any emphasis on test scores and reports on that front. There has been a massive misunderstanding and deliberate misinformation about this whole affair.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some things to think about.

As a minor, you're probably not going to be able to open a bank account nor sign an agreement for an apartment rental, let open start utilities for the apartment. You may also have problems getting a sim or local cell phone account. You may also have problems accessing medical care.

You may want to look for "boarding schools" who would be set up to act as "in loco parentis" while you are attending the school.